# What is the wrong here?

Tags: javascript, dom

I build a show & hide password application without any html just html, head, body elements and of course script element as a practice but there is wrong here :

```js
const inputOne = document.createElement('input');
const attrOne = document.createAttribute('type');
attrOne.value = 'password';
inputOne.setAttributeNode(attrOne);

const btnOne = document.createElement('button');
btnOne.innerHTML = 'Show Password';
document.body.appendChild(inputOne);

const BRBetween = document.createElement('br');
const BRsBetween = document.createElement('br');
document.body.appendChild(BRBetween);
document.body.appendChild(BRsBetween);
document.body.appendChild(btnOne);

const shHiPassword = function shHiPass() {
  if (inputOne.type == 'password') {
    inputOne.type = 'text';
    inputTwo.innerHtml = 'Hide Password';
  } else {
    inputOne.type = 'password'

    inputTwo.innerHtml = 'Show Password';
  }
};

const attrTwo = document.createAttribute('onclick');
attrTwo.value = shHiPassword;
btnOne.setAttributeNode(attrTwo);
```

its just give me password field and the button , when I click the button no thing happen .

I think the wrong in the function but I don't know where ...

Comment: It’s `innerHTML`, not `innerHtml`.

Comment: And `attrTwo.value = shHiPassword;` won’t work, because `shHiPassword` isn’t a string. The automatic string coercion won’t make it a useful value (just a function declaration, not a call). Why are you not using [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)? Why are you creating attribute nodes rather than simply using `setAttribute`?

Comment: Quick note: [Avoid `innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#Differences_from_innerHTML) if you're not using HTML. `textContent` is the faster option because it isn't parsed.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please remember to take the [tour], and please make sure to read ["how to ask a good question"](/help/how-to-ask) because "what is wrong" is a terrible title that doesn't tell anyone anything. Please read through that policy article, it doesn't take a lot of time, but does mean your questions will help not just you, but everyone else with a similar problem who finds your question in the future (which is _why_ Stackoverflow is so useful - questions are to help everyone, not just "you").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to fix you code and now you can try it, **It Will Work** as you desired.
I alredy used **click** event listener instead of set it to the element.
and replaced **setAttributeNodes** with **setAttribute**

```
const inputOne = document.createElement('input'),
      attrOne = document.createAttribute('type');

inputOne.setAttribute('type', 'password');
const btnOne = document.createElement('button');


btnOne.innerHTML = 'Show Password';
document.body.appendChild(inputOne);

const BRBetween = document.createElement('br');

const BRsBetween = document.createElement('br');

document.body.appendChild(BRBetween);
document.body.appendChild(BRsBetween);
document.body.appendChild(btnOne);

btnOne.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
if (inputOne.type == 'password') {
        inputOne.type = 'text';
        this.innerHTML = 'Hide Password';
 } else {
        inputOne.type = 'password';

    this.innerHTML = 'Show Password';
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your `onclick` attribute to a string value. Here's a working example:

```js
const inputOne = document.createElement('input');
const attrOne = document.createAttribute('type');
attrOne.value = 'password';
inputOne.setAttributeNode(attrOne);

const btnOne = document.createElement('button');
btnOne.innerHTML = 'Show Password';
document.body.appendChild(inputOne);

const BRBetween = document.createElement('br');
const BRsBetween = document.createElement('br');
document.body.appendChild(BRBetween);
document.body.appendChild(BRsBetween);
document.body.appendChild(btnOne);

function shHiPassword() {
  if (inputOne.type == 'password') {
    inputOne.type = 'text';
    btnOne.innerHTML = 'Hide Password';
  } else {
    inputOne.type = 'password'
    btnOne.innerHTML = 'Show Password';
  }
};

const attrTwo = document.createAttribute('onclick');
attrTwo.value = 'shHiPassword()';
btnOne.setAttributeNode(attrTwo);
```